# Как вставить изображение в двухколоночный документ с обтеканием текстом?

Tags: latex

Имеется PNG файл с прозрачностью (в данном случае Гном с изображения №2), необходимо вставить его на лист так же, как размещена голова гнома из изображения №1:

1) Изображение должно быть размещено по центру страницы (т.е между столбцами текста)

2) Необходимо, чтобы текст обтекал изображение по контуру (а не по квадратной рамке как на изображении №2)

Существует ли способ вставить изображение, выполнив требования выше с минимумом ручной работы (картинок планируется вставить большое количество)?

Вариант, представленный на изображении №2 получен с использованием следующих команд:

```html
\documentclass[oneside, twocolumn, final, 12pt] {extreport}
% "Русификация" документа
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
% Красная строка для первого параграфа
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% Добавляет возможность копирования текста из PDF файла
% Без этой строчки в буфер обмены попадает текст в кодировке
% отличной от utf-8 
\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Расы}
\section{Гномы}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Dwarf}
  \caption{Гном}
  \label{fig:image}
\end{wrapfigure}
Гномы известны за своё мастерство в искусстве магии. Их способности противостоять магическим воздействиям и неумной тягой к знаниям, а также тонкой обработкой камней и металлов, в которой они могут сравниться с эльфами. Гномы создают уникальные вещи или передают знания народам и расам.

\subsection{Индивидуальность}

Гномы очень общительны и часто попадаются среди различных, даже очень разнообразных рас в виде архивариусов, собирателей знаний. Они очень общительны, хотя и не любят когда им навязываются. Также они считают, что ум существа зависит от того сколько букв у них в имени. Они презирают тех кто берет в руки оружие, считая что искусство магии и знание гораздо выше. Гномы добры и считают что знания помогут им соединить разрозненные племена. Бывает что гномы пребывают в роли дипломатов и послов. Между своими родственниками дварфами и цвергами они служат прослойкой мирящей их и помогающей работать с волшебными вещами.
```

[image: Изображение №1]
[image: Изображение №2]

P.S OS Windows, используется MiKTeX 2.9, интерпретатор pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53073/79376

Comment: Я вам ответил ниже

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на сообщение от "alexander barakin" (текст сообщения не помещается в комментарий):

Попробовал pullquote, но все равно не получается желаемое.
Как устанавливал (текст из шпаргалки для себя):

1) Установить вручную pullquote, так как репозиторий MikTex на момент 16.12.2016 не имеет этого пакета в своих базах [1]

Процесс установки описан тут:
https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Hardware+and+Creative/9781784395148/2/ch02lvl1sec29/Creating%20a%20pull%20quote

> Download the pullquote.dtx file from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx
>   or from CTAN, once it's provided there too.
>
> Click on browse files and also download the pq-alice.jpg, pq-duck.pdf, and pullquote_test.tex files, to get filler images and a
>   sample file.
>
> Compile the pullquote.dtx file with LaTeX. Do it twice for correct references. It will generate a pullquote.sty file and the
>   documentation file pullquote.pdf. Place the files where your LaTeX can
>   find them, or simply in the document's folder.
>
> Start with a document class and the lipsum package for dummy text, and load the pullquote package:

Важно! Интерпритацию для получения файла pullquote.sty проводить в режиме pdfTex или pdfLaTex, при использовании выставленного по умолчанию интерпретатора pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex файл pullquote.sty не создается.

2) Для получения контура по изображению необходимо установить программу ImageMagick

Важно! При установке ImageMagick следует выбрать пункт "install legacy utilities".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иначе программа convert не будет установлена и при попытке её выхова будет вызываться стандартная программа convert Windows (которая имеет совсем другой функционал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(или в при установке pullrequest произвести в файле pullquote.dtx следующую правку:

```
   convert \img@pq\space -resize \strip@pt\@tempdima x\strip@pt\@tempdimb! -bordercolor white -border 10x10 -morphology Erode Disk:10.3 -resize
    \number\objrows@pq x\number\objlines@pq! -black-threshold
    95\@percentchar\space-monochrome \img@pq.pqshape.txt
```

заменить на

```
    magick \img@pq\space -resize \strip@pt\@tempdima x\strip@pt\@tempdimb! -bordercolor white -border 10x10 -morphology Erode Disk:10.3 -resize
    \number\objrows@pq x\number\objlines@pq! -black-threshold
    95\@percentchar\space-monochrome \img@pq.pqshape.txt
```

т.е convert -> magick)

Проверить что у вас все работает (или не работает), можно с помощью команды

```
convert pq-duck.pdf -resize 124.99362x123.20798! -bordercolor white -border 10x10 -morphology Erode Disk:10.3 -resize 26x13! -black-threshold 95% -monochrome pq-duck.pdf.pqshape.txt
```

или если модифицировали pullquote.dtx:

```
magick pq-duck.pdf -resize 124.99362x123.20798! -bordercolor white -border 10x10 -morphology Erode Disk:10.3 -resize 26x13! -black-threshold 95% -monochrome pq-duck.pdf.pqshape.txt
```

Команду выполнять из папки, содержащей файл pq-duck.pdf

!! Ошибка у меня где-то на этом этапе - команда для проверки выдает файл заполненный преимущественно нулями (как я понимаю, получившаяся фигура - прямоугольник).

Часть файла pq-duck.pdf.pqshape.txt:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 16,8,65535,srgb
0,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
1,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
2,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
3,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
8,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
9,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
10,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
11,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
12,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
13,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
14,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
15,0: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
0,1: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
1,1: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
2,1: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
3,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
8,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
9,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
```

2.1) Если вы получили ошибку "Не удается найти указанный файл. ЕсGswin32c.exe"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то вам необходимо установить Ghostscript Postscript and PDF interpreter/renderer

---

Тем не менее, мне все равно не удалось добиться необходимого результата - при создании документа pullquote.pdf уточка (в документе служит для проверки корректной работы) обрамлена по квадратной рамке, вместо обрамления по контуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]